# Why do I get a 404 for any new Action method in my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

In an ASP.NET MVC 4 project, I've added an MVC Controller with scaffolding from an EF class. I.e, CRUD operations. They all work. If I add action methods by hand, add an Html.ActionLink() to a view pointing to them, I get 404 errors.

For example, in my controller I add the AddImage method:

```
public ActionResult AddImage(int id)
{
    var car = db.Cars.Find(id);
    return View("AddImage",car);
}
```

This just returns a view to add images associated with the Car object. In the corresponding Index.cshtml, I add:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Image", "AddImage", new { id = item.CarId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "modal",OnSuccess="showDialog" })
```

When it renders, in the console, I see a 404 when that link is clicked. Another weird thing is that when I run in the debugger, a breakpoint set in the method is hollow with a little warning icon, says no executable code is associated with this line.

I have added nothing to the RouteConfig: it just has the Default, which should work. I had an overload with an HttpPost attribute, but even without that, I still get a 404.

In previous projects, I can Action methods with impunity and they all work. So what is the problem here?

Please help, Stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: Have you re-build and re-deployed the code?  Both symptoms (404 and the empty breakpoint) suggest not.

Comment: I've cleaned and re-built and restarted IIS Express. Still get the 404.

Comment: How are you deploying/running the code?  There's definitely a mismatch between what's running/debugging and what the browser is accessing.  If you put a breakpoint in a working action and request it in the browser, is the breakpoint hit?  Maybe manually kill IIS Express and close/re-open Visual Studio?

Comment: I was just hitting F5. However, after your last comment, I decided to keep doing more restarting. So I closed VS, deleted bin and obj, shut down IIS Express. Restart VS, open project, build, run. Now I get Parser Error, Could not load type MvcApplication in source file /global.asax. Weirdness.

Comment: Something's definitely mis-aligned with your whole setup, but I'm afraid unless somebody who's experienced it before stumbles across this then there just isn't enough conveyable information to really be helpful.  It's one of those things where "we can fix it if we can tinker with it."

Comment: I figured it out! I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of David in the comments, I think I figured out what I did to get my project in a weird state. To be brief: I added stuff to my model including adding a migration without calling Update-Database. I tried running the app without the database being up to date.

I wasn't getting an error that said as much, but after restarting VS, deleting the bin and obj folders for the project, changing the output path to just bin/ instead of bin/Debug (found on many Stackoverflow questions), I finally got the right error message.

Then I ran my update, et voila! Working project.

Answer (score 0):

write this

```
public ActionResult AddImage(int id)
{
    var car = db.Cars.Find(id);
    return View(car);
}
```

and your link must be 'AddImage' without empty space

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("AddImage", "AddImage", new { id = item.CarId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "modal",OnSuccess="showDialog" })
```